# php - Get Variable Text From Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using `simple_html_dom` to scrape some webpages and I need help. Here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var session = "";
    var order = "1";
    var status = "";
    var json_product = [{bla bla bla...}];
</script>
```

So I want to get inside `var json_produk = ...` is meaning:

```
[{"bla.... bla... bla... until }];
```

How can I get it?

I am trying for:

```
$html->find('var', 2);
```

I just get a 500 error because find use for find string I think.

Comment: this is very unreadable. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: where of part you can read ? i'am sorry i just beggening in here.

Comment: Based on the code you posted `var json_produk` has value. Im not sure what format do you need.

Comment: Put new line on your code so that people can see it. Format it properly.

Comment: i can't edit "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: @Eddie i'am trying but getting erroor It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: @Eddie yes, i want to get the value and i want to convert it from php

Comment: @CSMMedia Put some additional text so that you can save it.

Comment: i remove some useless script but still get error

Comment: Thanks for Mr @Leopold Joy

Comment: @CSMMedia You mean, you want to access each value on the a `json_produk` variable. Right?

Comment: @Eddie yes, you all right, is posibble to me to get it, i want to extract the json product.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using [an HTML parser] to scrape some webpages

But the value you want is in javascript (which is embedded in the HTML).

While you can retrieve the entire block of javascript with the DOM parser, that's as much resolution as it will give you.

```
$script=$html->find('script') . ''; // not tested - YMMV
```

PHP does not have a Javascript parser. If you can be sure that the JSON will always be assigned to "json_product" and that there is no further javascript code, then you could.....

```
$srch='json_product =';
$start=strpos($script, $srch);
$json=substr($script, $start+strlen($srch)+1);
$data=json_decode($json);
```

....but this is a long way from a robust solution.

> I just get a 500 error because find use for find string I think.

That should not cause "a 500 error"

Comment: thanks my problem is solved mr @symcbean, i using substr and strpos too, about a 500 error yeah really, i getting 500 error, HTTP ERROR 500